# I tried to add border on content

Tags: css

This code doesn't work to add Border line on published content jobs by customers or users please check the photo below.

```
.job-overview-content {
    background-color: your color;
    border-color: your color;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you really set the colour as *your color*?

Comment: for border top, try `border-top: 1px solid black;` . Play around with the pixels and color.

Comment: No, i just copied and posted here, simple check the picture... lol

Comment: The reason is that when i add the code border doesn't show up

Comment: Show the html markup please. I just tried your code and it does show a 10px border.

Comment: I'm using localhost where to find html markup

Comment: is it xampp? go to xampp -> htdocs -> wherever your file is.

Comment: Yes, i went to xampp > htdocs > testsite , now which file should i show you 
https://prnt.sc/pgpkeo

Comment: You are using wordpress. Go to your wp-admin, login , go to the page where this is and then screen show the code there. You have to add the class there if it isn't there.

Answer (score -1):

Can be some general class overriding border property or wrong class name. Try to post some fiddle with html + css.